# Restkit 0.20: Handling mapping to abstract entities

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

My app can receive something like the following from the server:

```
{
    'data': [{
          'class': 'B',
          'id': ...,
          ...
     },
     {
          'class': 'C',
          'id': ...,
          ...
     }]
}
```

where `B` and `C` are descendents of `A`.

In my app, my coredata model reflects the server i.e. an abstract entity `A` and descendents `B and`C. Using the above response I then need to map `data[0]` and `data[1]` onto entities of type `B` and `C` respectively.

As far as I can tell so far, RESTKit is only able to discern how to map an entity via the URL pattern and a key path e.g.:

```
RKResponseDescriptor *resourceDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:mapping method:RKRequestMethodAny pathPattern:@"A/" keyPath:@"data" statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:HttpResponseCodeSuccess]];
```

which means that the above objects end up being mapped onto entities of type `A`. Am I wrong in this? If not are there any ways round this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're half right, RestKit can also use dynamic mapping. But that won't really help you (mainly because the data is an array).

The only workaround (and it is a workaround because RestKit is not designed for this scenario) would be to create response descriptors for each entity type and allow them all to run on the response. Then, use [KVC validation](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping#key-value-validation) to reject any mappings which are for the wrong class type.

It would be sensible to use [mogenerator](http://rentzsch.github.io/mogenerator/) so that your model classes are maintained sensibly as your validation logic would live there.